# What does the "$\|$" symbol mean in "$\;p_i(j) \propto \exp \{ - \| A x_i - A x_j \|_2^2\}\;$"?

Tags: probability, notation

I am trying to understand [this](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Ezemel/documents/knca_camera.pdf) paper, but in this paper the following "$\|$" symbol is frequently used.

$$p_i(j) \propto \exp \{ - \| A x_i - A x_j \|_2^2\}$$

I wonder to know what does it mean, what are these two "$2$"s doing here?

And also wonder to know does the above "$\|$" symbol has different meaning than the below "$\|$" symbol (considering there is only one "$2$" here)?

$$p_i(j) \propto \exp \left\{ -\dfrac{\|x_i - x_j\|^2}{2 \sigma_i^2} \right\}$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $||\cdot||$ is the norm. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28mathematics%29

Comment: what are those two `2`?

Comment: The lower $2$ probably means it's the 2-norm (the standard euclidean distance), and the upper is probably just an exponent.

Comment: Machine learning: because notation is fun!